# Graphics3D/Plot3D rendering issue

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, rendering

I have an issue in *Mathematica* with the rendering of 3D graphics. Two sides (right and bottom) of some sort of bounding box are present, and, in the instance of `Plot3D`, for example, the labels are quite low in resolution. I have uninstalled *Mathematica* 10.1 (where I first noticed the problem), attempted to reset *Mathematica* to its default configuration by deleting both the Base Directory and the User Base Directory (as instructed [here](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12464)), and even installed a new, updated *Mathematica* 10.3 to no avail:  the rendering problem persists.  It only occurs on one computer that I use, so I'm not sure what the issue might be. I've included a couple of images to better illustrate the issue. Any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]
[image]

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Windows. I've tried this on another identical-model laptop as well as other computers without this issue, so there's something seemingly specific to my configuration that is causing the problem.

Comment: I have same issue in my window 7 system for long time. but in other machine with window 10 I don't have it. I remember I tried to solve it previously but I stopped.

Comment: Try anti-aliasing?

Comment: I would start by looking for an updated driver for your video card (which I imagine is from Intel).

Comment: @thedude **turning off** antialiasing seems to improve the rendering of the numbers on the axes of `Plot3D` a bit. The two sides of the "bounding box" remain, however, and diagonal lines look a bit more choppy in general due to the lack of antialiasing.

Comment: I also have Eclipse and Android Studio installed on this laptop. Could I have enabled some setting (particularly with Android Studio) that might be causing this rendering issue?

Answer (score 1):

Works fine on my system, but you might try over-riding your ticks by:

```
Plot3D[x + y, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Italic, 18]]
```

Try:

```
Graphics3D[Cuboid[], ImagePadding -> 50]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, David! Unfortunately, that does not help with the rendering issues. Though larger, the labels are still low resolution, and the two-sided "bounding box" is still there. Do you think it's something beyond Mathematica that is causing the issue?

Comment: Hmmm....  I have never experienced that problem.  I can only imagine that somehow your fonts are not properly installed.  Try:  `TicksStyle -> Directive[Italic, 18, FontFamily -> "Times"]`.  Otherwise, I have no idea how to help.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also doesn't fix the issues. I appreciate your trying, though!

Comment: Also, I should say that it's more than just the font rendering issue. There is also the issue of the unpleasant two-sided "bounding box".